# How do I add a custom predicate-builder in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 4, If I had an `ArrayLikeClass` class and I wanted to use its objects in where queries like `Model.where(id: instance_of_array_like_class)`, I could do so by registering a predicate-builder:

```
ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder.register_handler(ArrayLikeClass, ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::ArrayHandler.new)
```

after which instances of `ArrayLikeClass` would behave same as instances of `Array` when used in where queries.

However, with Rails 5, the API is changed and `ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::ArrayHandler.new` now requires an instance of `ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder`. Also `register_handler` is now an *instance method* in `ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder`.

So, how can I register a predicate-builder handler in Rails 5 for a custom class?

Comment: is this https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L60 by any chance what you're looking for ?

Comment: @fanta Somewhat yes, but instead of mentioning a table/model, I'd like to make it available to all models. Also, I'd prefer to reuse existing `ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::ArrayHandler.new` but it requires an instance of `ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder` which I'm not sure where to find.

Comment: Ok, I think it is not possible now, looks like it was changed here https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a3936bbe21f4bff8247f890cacfd0fc882921003, if you see, the method is now an instance method instead of a class method. Check the tests.

Answer (score 2):

While this is an old question, I came across a similar problem but I was wanting to use a custom handler too. One was you could do this is by registering a handler in your model in the predicate_builder method. You could do this in a base model, module or however, but if you where to do in the base model for example it would look like this:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.predicate_builder
    return @local_predicate_builder if @local_predicate_builder
    @local_predicate_builder = super
    @local_predicate_builder.register_handler(ArrayLikeClass, ArrayLikeClassHandler.new(@local_predicate_builder))
    @local_predicate_builder
  end
  ...
end
```

While this uses a custom handler class you could try changing the `ArrayLikeClassHandler` to `ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::ArrayHandler` but I only tried this with a custom handler.

Here is a link to the method in ActiveRecord [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L277).